# Ucfirst for the specific chracter in the string in php

Tags: php

Here i have my string `01Texdox`

I want the output like `01TexDox`.How can i achieve this ?

What i have tried in **mysql** is

```
UPDATE test1 SET test_char = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(test_char, 1)), SUBSTRING(test_char, 2));
```

**In php**

```
$var = "01Texdox";

echo ucfirst($var);
```

how can i achieve this in php ?

Comment: Give us more examples to see what is the common pattern. If i have another string `01Texdoxmox`should it be `01TexDoxMox` or `01TextDoxmox` ?

Comment: `$var = "01Texdox";
$var[5] = strtoupper($var[5]);`

Comment: `01TexDox` i need like this @AkramFares

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: that wont come like that `01TexDox ` just it will be like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = "01Texdox";

$var[5] = strtoupper($var[5]);

echo $var ;
```